# PseudoTCPSocket by google

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, webrtc

I'm implementing our WebRTC communication and I got stuck with pseudo tcp socket in libnice (which is copied from libjingle).

What does a pseudo TCP socket do and why it is even needed?

https://github.com/vigsterkr/libjingle/blob/master/talk/p2p/base/pseudotcp.cc
https://github.com/libnice/libnice/blob/master/agent/pseudotcp.c

Answer (score 0):

pseudotcp was used by libjingle for providing filetransfer with tcp-like reliability on top of udp back in 2005. It is not used by WebRTC which uses SCTP for similar purposes.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answer. As far as I can tell it is used by ice agent which is part of webrtc.

Comment: Do you know what does it do to be tcp-like reliable?